# MPMoviePlayerController failing to stream .3gp video since iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an existing iPhone/iPad universal app that streamed video with the MPMoviePlayerController over wi-fi (mp4) and 3G Network (3gp). When iOS 4.3 was released our 4.3 devices can no longer play a 3gp video over 3G network. I tested a local 3gp file and that fails too, but works on a 3G phone running 4.2.x.

After debugging the view controller I see the  MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification notification is not being triggered when trying to play the 3gp file locally or streaming it via URL.

```
[APPDEL showStatusView:  @"Please wait..."];

    NSString * videoUrl = [[request.URL description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"idvideo:" withString: @"http:"];
    DLog(@"Loading video %@", videoUrl);
    _moviePlayer = [[IDMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString: videoUrl]];
    _moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;

    _moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) {
        // May help to reduce latency
        [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

        // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                                                             object:_moviePlayer];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerPreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:_moviePlayer];


        //[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerTimerUp:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }  
    else {
        // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                                                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                                                             object:nil];
    }       

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(onMovieDone:) name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object: nil];

    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector: @selector(view)]) {
        [self.view addSubview: _moviePlayer.view];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        }
        else {
            _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
        }

        _moviePlayer.view.frame = _webView.frame;
    }

    [_moviePlayer play];
```

The first condition for the loadState is always hit. For the 3gp file the code will never reach the moviePlayerLoadStateChanged selector method which hides an indicator/status view and creates other fullscreen/orientation notifications. The indicator/status view will just remain up & spinning. Within debugger I can see the onMovieDone selector method gets triggered far sooner than the video would of really of finished.

Confused.

Answer (score 0):

This my answer in regards with playing ***.3gp*** file with iPhone .....**I have successfully played .3gp file with iphone sdk** with using ***MpMoviePlayerController*** and my answer link is:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088808/1092219

hope you will got help from my answer.........!! :))))))