# How to play a video file from the URL of type .3gp

Tags: iphone

Thanks in advance. I want to implement the code to play a video in iphone programatically from URL. I have written the code like this .

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://91.220.127.40/Celebrity_subCategoryItems/rc4.3gp"];//@"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:     url];
[[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];
```

but it is not playing the file of type .3gp. If any one know please help me.

Comment: Which part of the Apple documentation told you to use 3GP files?

Comment: I don't know Till. Is it not possible to use 3gp file in iphone.

Comment: Well, 3GP is a slightly restricted MP4 format - hence it might work but often enough it does not. The format/s of your choice are MP4 (M4V) for progressive download or M3U8 (HTTP video streaming) for proper, adaptive streaming. You should really consult the well written Apple documents.

Answer (score 3):

I have played successfully .3gp with iphone sdk and my code is :

```
NSString *soundLocalPath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Demo_video" ofType:@"3gp"];

NSURL *tempUrl   = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundLocalPath];

self.soundUrlPath = tempUrl;

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: self.soundUrlPath];

self.mpMoviePlayer = player;

[player release];

[self.mpMoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.mpMoviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

[self.view addSubview: self.mpMoviePlayer.view];

[self.mpMoviePlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:player];


-(void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    [player autorelease];
}
```

Comment: where MPMoviePlayerController *mpMoviePlayer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mpMoviePlayer;

are defined in .h file.

Answer (score 0):

We can also able to play files with .3gp extension, but to play we need some compression standards for that converted the file into all mobile supported formats means (3GPP - Mobile Balanced Quality [H.263 near 128 kbps, 10 fps, 128*96; AMR)). So it is playing now.

Comment: hi @Vennela can you please tell me how to compress this video in standard formats?Thanks in advance