# Can not play video from URL in iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video

I'm having a problem playing the video from URL-based. This is my code:

```
-(void)clickplay
{ 
   NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov"];
   MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
   [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)];
   [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
   moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
   [moviePlayerController play];
}
```

It compiles successfully and the player did pop out but it just keeps loading forever... I have tried changing the URL several times to no effect. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: Added the *objective-c* tag. Please remove if this is not applicable.

Comment: you can try to download the mov, and then test again to verify the codec is ready.I find nothing with your code snippet.

Comment: thank you but I have tried download the mov successfully on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retain a reference to the moviePlayerController.  It's getting released and preventing any delegated messages from being invoked.  Probably the easiest place to put it is in the class that contains the `- (void)clickplay` implementation.  That is, add a new instance variable called `moviePlayerController` and assign it the newly created `MPMoviePlayerController` object in `clickplay`.

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the code you tried?

Comment: I upload my file to here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D99AED80C7C9708!239

Comment: Problem is gone. I open a new project and re-write all code then it works correctly...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
videoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480);

     [videoPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];

    [videoPlayer play];

    videoPlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;

    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoPlayer];

/* configuring notification*/
- (void)moviePlayBackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [videoPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: thank you I have tried this but it still keep loading....I upload my file to here:https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D99AED80C7C9708!239

Comment: Problem is gone. I open a new project and re-write all code then it works correctly...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This my answer in regards with playing **.3gp** file with iPhone .....**I have successfully played .3gp file with iphone sdk**  with using ***MpMoviePlayerController*** and my answer link is:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088808/1092219

hope you will got help from my answer.........!! :))))))